# Can simple protobuf types be migrated to "optional"

Tags: protocol-buffers

In protobuf version 3 `required` and `optional` keywords first have been removed, since `required` often caused problems [protobuf issue 2497](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2497).

Recently the 'optional' keyword has been reintroduced [protobuf v3.15.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0).

Is it possible to simply add the optional keyword to an existing message?

I.e. change

```
message Test {
    int32 int32_value = 1;
    string text_value = 2;
}
```

to

```
message Test {
    optional int32 int32_value = 1;
    optional string text_value = 2;
}
```

Or will this break the binary format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`non-optional` primitive types in protobuf don't accept `null`-values and normally also map to non-nullable types like `int` in Java or C#.
But this doesn't mean, that the field is always included in the binary representation.

In fact, if a field contains the default value for the corresponding type the field is omitted in the binary representation.

Thus the following message

```
message Test {
    int32 int32_value = 1;
    string text_value = 2;
}

Test test = new Test();
byte[] buffer = test.ToByteArray();
```

gets serialized to `buffer` containing an empty `byte[]`.
So missing fields default to default values without the use of optional.

If the optional keyword is changing the behaviour for missing fields in the binary format and for default values specified:
Missing fields indicate the field has not been specified and indicate `null`. Setting default values will not result in an empty `byte[]` but in the default values being serialized.

Thus changing a primitive field to optional won't break the format, but will change the semantics:

All fields of old messages that have been specified with the default value will be interpreted as `null`. Other values are not affected.

The same for optional being removed from a field:
The api won't break, but change semantics. Unspecified fields will then default to default values for the corresponding type.

Comment: Also note that if messages with the added `optional` keyword gets processed in some old intermediate node w/o the `optional` keyword, then all the fields explicitly set to default values (0 or empty strings or bytes) will be unset.

Comment: @AlexChe Very good point. I think this would be dependant on the language and the implementation of the intermediate node. I.e. if the intermediate node stores the binary and forwards it as is, there won't be a change.
But everyone should keep this szenario in mind when changeing semantics.